# Js scripts with src link won't work when injected using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple ajax script that inject slider or any script   using    html()  function in jQuery

I noticed if I added js link in src  it won't get executed  and I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

when I inject owlCarousel code directly  it will work normally

I tried to inject the urls  using this function

```
<script>

        function load_js(url) {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url;
            head.appendChild(script);
        }

        load_js("{{url('widgets/sliders/slider3/js/owl.carousel.min.js')}}");


        //---------------------------------------------------------
        //this code won't work  as if the link above is not exists
        //---------------------------------------------------------
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#cl-tesimonial").owlCarousel({
            navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
            navigationText: [
                "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
                "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"
            ],

            autoPlay:true,
            pagination: true,
            slideSpeed : 1000,
            paginationSpeed : 1000,
            singleItem:true,
            transitionStyle : "backSlide",

        });
    });
</script>
```

but also same issue

I don't want to inject whole js in my html file   I want to inject the link only
so it get cached

is there anyway to fix this issue ?
This issue happens with any js file

Comment: Can you check the network tab, on what URL is sending the request to get the URL and is it giving 404 or not?

Comment: @SwarajGandhi   I can see it  as Status Code: 200       it's working normally

Comment: Try to move your load_js  outside of document ready.

Comment: @ikiK  I tried to do that but it didn't work either  it will only work  if I injected whole js code in html file but  won't work  if the js code called using src  link